# Multiple Qt Bluetooth Low Energy servers on one device using Qt?

Tags: qt, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

I want to expose multiple BLE services from one device using Qt (on linux), but don't know how to do it if it's even possible.

In my specific case I want my device to be both a heart rate service (HRS) and a cycling power service (CPS).

My testing code is very similar to the heart rate server example from Qt's documentation, http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtbluetooth-heartrate-server-main-cpp.html, and I've tried the following two approaches:

1. Using two QLowEnergyControllers from one application
2. Using one QLowEnergyController, but adding two different services using bleController->addService().

However it doesn't seems like either one is working properly, or it is just the apps I use for testing that doesn't really handles this properly.  I currently use my iPhone 6s with TrainerRoad for testing, and if I just expose one of the services it works well.

Can this be done, and if so, what is the correct way?

Answer (score 1):

I retried this a while back and could successfully provide multiple services using one device. The correct way is to use option 2, so one QLowEnergyController and then add multiple services.

Unfortunately I didn't keep the code from my first attempt, so I can't provide a good answer of what I did wrong. But it works "as expected", no special stuff is needed.